# TypeError:integer argument expected int got float in opencv circle

Tags: opencv, contour, opencv3.0

I have made a hand gesture mouse controller using opencv, but when i run the code 
I got this error on cv2.circle...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Arne/PycharmProjects/JARVISv2/Virtual.py", line 65, in <module>
cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), (w + h) / 4, (0, 0, 255), 2)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (674) 
SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback

Process finished with exit code 1
```

*Please somebody help me, I am bit closer to complete my Project* 
**THANKS IN ADVANCE**
Here is my code--

```
    if (len(conts) == 2):
    if (pinchFlag == 1):
        pinchFlag = 0
        mouse.release(Button.left)
    x1, y1, w1, h1 = cv2.boundingRect(conts[0])
    x2, y2, w2, h2 = cv2.boundingRect(conts[1])
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x1 + w1, y1 + h1), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x2, y2), (x2 + w2, y2 + h2), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cx1 = int(x1 + w1 // 2
```

)
        cy1 = int(y1 + h1 // 2
)
        cx2 = int (x2 + w2 // 2
)
        cy2 = int(y2 + h2 // 2
)
        cx = (cx1 + cx2) / 2
        cy = (cy1 + cy2) / 2
        cv2.line(img, (cx1, cy1), (cx2, cy2), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 2, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        mouseLoc = (sx - (cx * sx / camx), cy * sy / camy)
        mouse.position = mouseLoc
        while mouse.position != mouseLoc:
            pass

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide integer coordinates to cv2.line and cv2.circle(). Change cx and cy to int(cx1) and int(cy1) or perhaps just int(cx1,cy1) and similarly for cx2 and cy2. Or when dividing by 2 use // rather / for division so as to create integer values.

Comment: I do this but still get the same Error.

Comment: (w + h) / 4 is float

Comment: (w + h) // 4 the same as you did for the cx and cy. See python documentation for // operator. Or int((w+h)/4). You do not need both int() and /, thought it won't hurt. https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/floor_division.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are annoyed at the unpythonic blunder of requiring int, an ugly and incompatible change on a minor release (4.5.2), you can undo this:

```
import cv2

def monkeypatch_cv2():
    v = tuple(map(int, cv2.__version__.split('.')))

    if (v >= (4,5,2)) and cv2.circle.__name__ != 'monkey_circle':
        old_circle = cv2.circle
        old_line = cv2.line

        def monkey_circle(img, center, *args, **kwargs):
            old_circle(img, tuple(map(int, center)), *args, **kwargs)

        def monkey_line(img, pt1, pt2, *args, **kwargs):
            old_line(img, tuple(map(int, pt1)), tuple(map(int, pt2)), *args, **kwargs)

        cv2.circle = monkey_circle
        cv2.line = monkey_line


monkeypatch_cv2()
```

That way, you don't need to fix all your perfectly good working code that uses float.